# Android: Disable application for tablet

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen-support, android-screen

I developed an application, Now i want to restrict the application for tablet.

Means the application should not run on any tablets. For that I specify the support-screens in Androidmenifest.XML file as:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.abc.xyz"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
    android:allowBackup="true" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.abc.xyz.activities.hello"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hello" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
</application>

</manifest>
```

Now the issue is that :

**Application is running on tablet**

```
 android:largeScreens="false"
 android:xlargeScreens="false"
```

**After declaring above too.**

Now what should i do. Please suggest me and guide me.

Comment: how you have tested it???by uploading it on play store??

Comment: Please check this link it might help you : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: Akram : Yes i tested it. It is visible for tab. I tested from tab.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Include following in your Manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
</manifest>
```

This will help you.

Comment: Don't forget to add xxhdpi, which was added in API 16

Comment: @EduardK. but most of the xxhdpi devices belong to Tabs. so why to include that?

Comment: @Satyam because there are xxhdpi devices that are not tablets, such as Nexus 5.

Comment: @Satyam ...and the display technology is only improving, so it's likely we'll have more and more xxhdpi devices fitted into a medium screen bucket in the future.

Comment: <!-- all normal size screens -->

 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

This Value is repeating. Is this right ?  Is it right that we replace the "small"  with "Normal" for this 3 option?

Answer (score 38):

This prevents access on tablets, but allows the new density buckets (**xxhdpi** and **xxxhdpi**) and avoids errors on projects that are compiled against lower SDKs. It should be a direct child of the `<manifest>` element in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

***Update 8.8.2016***
Add this line if you want to support Nexus-5x-like devices with 420 density

```
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
```

Comment: I was missing all kinds of devices, this fixed that! Thanks!

Comment: Will this work if my app already supports tablet and I don't want the tablets to get an update to a specific version ?

Comment: With this configuration, devices like Nexus 5x(~423 ppi) are not included. Tested. You still have to add xxhdpi.

Comment: What is mean by <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />

Comment: I believe it would be according to the [API docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html).  The screenDensity attribute declares the dpi, and all of these are valid dpi values in the docs.

Comment: I dont think is correct answer anymore. I could not install app on Samsung Galaxy S9+

Comment: any new method now?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to restrict the app to handsets only use the `<compatible-screens>` tag in the Manifest. i.e.like this

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

For more info check [**Declaring an App is Only for Handsets**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps)

You should not use the `<supports-screens>` tag, if you want to restrict the app from tablets. It is clearly mentioned in the [**official doc**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps)

> **Caution**: If you use the  element for the reverse
>   scenario (when your application is not compatible with larger screens)
>   and set the larger screen size attributes to "false", then external
>   services such as Google Play do not apply filtering. Your application
>   will still be available to larger screens, but when it runs, it will
>   not resize to fit the screen. Instead, the system will emulate a
>   handset screen size (about 320dp x 480dp; see Screen Compatibility
>   Mode for more information). If you want to prevent your application
>   from being downloaded on larger screens, use , as
>   discussed in the previous section about Declaring an App is Only for
>   Handsets.

Answer (score 1):

please check if you have made layout for layout-large, layout-xlarge. if they are present your app will run on tablet, please remove that layout folder if present.