# Android App Update issue with Compatible Screen in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I simple wish to restrict my app to tablet .

In version 1.0 of my app is completely visible to all devices and 2.3 above OS .

In version 1.1 I have updated manifest entry following the Google Developer Guideline , My app update 1.1 is not visible to xxhpi and xxxhpi devices ..etc in Play Store Android App and rest of device are receiving it.

Though the xxdhpi and xxxhdpi like nexus 5 , nexus 6 are in the supported devices listing in Google App Publishing Console

Following these guideline 
[Link 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)
[Link 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps) 
[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229589/android-disable-application-for-tablet)

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />


<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I created a fake app and tested .These are the entry for manifest.xml config which will restrict your app to tablet and completely visible on Large screen on Phone (5 inch to 6 inch ) like Nexus 5 , 6

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

[image]