# What is range for android:largeScreens?

Tags: android, mobile, android-manifest, tablet, screen-size

[image]

As per the above image, large screen size will have range of 4" to 7".

So all the android devices which have 4" to 7" display size they all belongs to large screen size.

It may chance 7" tablet also part of this category.

A reason to ask this question that I need to restrict app for tablet users.

So I have set following configuration in manifest file.

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" 
              android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Still app is getting visible for tablet.

Just want to know **android:largeScreens** is for tablet or mobile?

I have also refereed  [Android: Disable application for tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229589/android-disable-application-for-tablet).

In this he has used only **normalScreens**. But normal screen size range is 3-5 inch. What if device is 5-6 inch.

Please give me clarification about screen wise range.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Above specification of diagram is 2 to 4 is for phone :

`android:smallScreens="true"`

`android:normalScreens="true"`

This effect for app in playstore then open in only phone.

`android:largeScreens="true"` use for Tablete and Phone (5',7'tablete and large phone like nexus).

`android:xlargeScreens="true"` use for Tablete (7' and 10') open.